# How to stop window.onresize event when scroll ? I only need to fire once?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried all the way, but window.onresize still fire when swiping up or down on the page.

First, I try a basic command line:

```
window.onresize = function (event) {
  setTimeout(Orientation,500);
}

function Orientation() {
 if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
   alert("Portrait");
  }
else {
   alert("Landscape");
  }
}
```

When alert show up, i click OK. But when i swiping up or down on the page, alert show up again, alway like that...

I will try jquery's David Walsh:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

var myEfficientFn = debounce(function() {
    if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
   alert("Portrait");
  }
else {
   alert("Landscape");
  }
}, 250);

window.addEventListener('resize', myEfficientFn);
```

The result is the same!

You can try here by Mobile or Tablet: http://hangaumy.com/test.html

Is there any other way for this event ? Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Put a condition in your function so your function only fires when you want it to.

```js
window.onresize = doSomething;
var count=0
function doSomething(x) {
if(count<1){
    alert('Go' + x);
    }
    count+=1;
}
```

Comment: WOW, AMAZING, IT'S DONE !!! Thanks for your beautiful help ! But Window.resize event stop now, i want it run one time when Window.resize ?

Comment: I don't think you realize the point I am making. Stop your function from firing and not the event. Take out the timeout and put it in your function. Do not use "if else" make two separate conditions. Not everything is "if else"

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to use event resize in this case but I found another solution:

```
var orien = '';
setInterval(function() {
  if (window.innerHeight >= window.innerWidth && orien != 'Portrait') {
    alert('Portrait');
    orien = 'Portrait';
    return;
  }
  if (window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth && orien != 'Landscape') {
    alert('Landscape');
    orien = 'Landscape';
  }
}, 500);
```

Comment: No effect for window.resize event ?

Comment: Sorry, that my mistake, I can't find a way to use event resize in this case but I found another solution. I add code to the answer. Take a look at it